# Как в postgres повернуть таблицу аналогично crosstab

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

Как можно преобразовать таблицу так, чтобы на столбцах были 
значения столбцов `question_name`?

Я смотрел, конечно, как это делается с [crosstab-ом](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_crosstab.html), но там явно указывается структура (т.е. названия столбцов и тип).

Проблема в том, что значений `question_name` может быть сколь угодно много, и они могут принимать абсолютно любые значения.

Есть ли способ делать это независимо от количества значений `question_name`?

Буду благодарен за любую поддержку!

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, на основе данных в вопросе, пример того, как должна выглядеть повернутая таблица

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Исходная модель:

```
create table testData (
    id serial primary key,
    survey_id int,
    question_name varchar(50),
    option_name varchar(50)
);

insert into testData (survey_id, question_name, option_name) values 
(1, 'Заканчивая', 'C0'),
(1, 'Варианты спондилодеза', 'A-IF'),
(1, 'Основная патология', 'Дегенеративное заболевание'),
(1, 'Начиная', 'C0'),
(2, 'Заканчивая', 'C0'),
(2, 'Основная патология', 'Опухоль'),
(2, 'Начиная', 'T2'),
(2, 'Варианты спондилодеза', 'LLIF'),
(3, 'Заканчивая', 'T11'),
(3, 'Основная патология', 'Деформация'),
(3, 'Варианты спондилодеза', 'TLIF'),
(3, 'Начиная', 'T2');
```

Из-за статического характера определения типа, возвращаемого функцией `crosstab`, решаем задачу в 2 захода.

### Получаем текст SQL запроса в некую переменную:

```
select '
    select *
    from crosstab(
        ''select survey_id, question_name, option_name
         from testData
         order by survey_id, question_name;'',
        ''select distinct question_name from testData order by 1''
    ) as ct(survey_id int, ' || 
    (select string_agg('"' || question_name || '" text',', ') 
        from (
            select distinct question_name from testData
            order by question_name
        ) as q
    ) || ');'
```

### Выполняем полученный текст:

```
select *
from crosstab(
    'select survey_id, question_name, option_name
     from testData
     order by survey_id, question_name;',
    'select distinct question_name from testData order by 1'
) as ct(survey_id int, "Варианты спондилодеза" text, "Заканчивая" text, "Начиная" text, "Основная патология" text);
```

### Результат:

```
survey_id   Варианты спондилодеза   Заканчивая  Начиная Основная патология
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           A-IF                    C0          C0      Дегенеративное заболевание
2           LLIF                    C0          T2      Опухоль
3           TLIF                    T11         T2      Деформация
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это тот результат, которого я ожидал. Только хотелось бы уточнить есть ли способ, чтобы последнюю строку не указывать явно? as ct(survey_id int, "Варианты спондилодеза" text, "Заканчивая" text, "Начиная" text, "Основная патология" text)? так как таких данных со временем может стать больше.

Comment: Именно из-за последней строчки и приходится городить этот огород с двумя независимыми запросами. Сервер не может выполнить динамическую типизацию. Почитайте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36831103/9921853), [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39782514/9921853) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41295389/9921853)

Comment: Понятно, благодарю за ответ!